# No errors in my program, but it is not printing out what i would like it to

Tags: java, output

My assignment is as follows:

> Create a program which will remove the first and last characters of a string. The program should then remove the next set of outside characters. The program continues in this fashion until it has hit the middle character or the middle two characters, completing a Word Pyramid. *using recursion*

So I've made my program and it has no errors but yet it is not printing out the word string within the "wordPyramid" method I created.

If the user entered the word "pyramid" I would like the program output:

pyramid
yrami
ram
a

Here's my code:

```
package wordpyramid;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Wordpyramid {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Ask user what word they would like to "pyramid"
        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What word would you like to " + "'pyramid'?");
        wordPyramid(input);
    }

    //Create word pyramid method
    public static String wordPyramid(String word) {
        int length = word.length();
        if (word.length() == 1) {
            return word;
        } else {
            return word = wordPyramid(word.substring(1, length-1));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This, `"No errors in my program, but it is not printing out what i would like it to"` -- cannot possibly be true. If it's not printing out correctly, if it's not behaving as expected, then yes, your program **must** have a **logical** error. Don't confuse lack of compiler errors with lack of logical errors. You can have the latter without the former.

Comment: You're not printing anything. in your wordPyramid method you need System.out.println(word).

Comment: instead of returning the work variable, you should just print it. it is not printing anything at all because you are never printing anything at all, are you? The logic is correct anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the string by doing `System.out.println(word);`

```
public static String wordPyramid(String word) {
    int length = word.length();
    System.out.println(word);   //printing word
    if (word.length() == 1) {
        return word;
    } else {

        return word = wordPyramid(word.substring(1, length - 1));
    }

}
```

output

```
pyramid
yrami
ram
a
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/TH2uyd)

Comment: for some reason I had thought that simply returning word would print it out ahaha. thank you.